# Company page needs Facebook profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

I've got a company web app. I have integrated it without much problems with Twitter.

This means, when a staff of our company creates a new product, it posts onto the company's profile on the Twitter web site as well.

However, Facebook is another story. Facebook encourages registrants to sign up as "individuals".

For example, on the registration page:

1. You are not allowed to put generic emails such as (support@company_email.com, sales@company_email.com)
2. You may not have the first and last name as a company entity. For example Foo Distribution or Foo Inc

Their automated system simply rejects any clever attempts to register as a "non-individual". With Twitter, it was a breeze. Since Twitter allows / encourages companies to register an account with them directly, and not as individuals.

Moving along on Facebook, I found out that I can create a 'page'. Which I can use for the company. It has the option of allowing other "individuals" to be admin of the page. However, this would mean that each staff would need a Facebook account.

I don't really like this approach, since some of our staff may be negligent with their Facebook passwords. I rather have our web app have one 'method' of accessing Facebook's API isntead, the way it is done with Twitter.

How else would you go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make yourself the admin of the page, install an app that you develop, and then let your users make posts to the page through that app. This way, you're controlling access to the page while letting your users still have access to it.

You'll need to use an `offline_access`-enabled access token for this to work continuously ([permissions documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)), and if that token changes, you'll have to log in yourself and refresh that token (it can change when you change your password or uninstall/reinstall the app). Additionally you'll need a `manage_pages` permission, and you'll need to use the `access_token` for your page that you can find in `/me/accounts` to make posts to the page.

Comment: But doesn't this look a bit inconsistent. I am using omniauth for authentication. This means, I have one account for Twitter and several accounts for Facebook? Is there a more elegant approach to doing this?

Comment: I don't know much about omniauth (read: never heard of it) but yes, you'll need to keep track of two access tokens per page you want to post on, and you need to hook that up to a user profile.

Comment: Otherwise, I was thinking of creating a foo.bar@company_name.com and storing this access token. When a staff creates a product, the system uses foo bar's access token to post to the page. Any thoughts?

Comment: The Facebook account you're using needs to be a full account (not just the limited one you can sign up for to manage pages from the live site) in order to install apps to it. So if you're planning on managing your page from within your app, you'll need to hook it up to a full account. It doesn't need to be yours, but it needs to be a regular, full account with the ability to install apps.